# AWS Step function: How to pass a static key value pair in state machine (Without using type: pass)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We have a generic lambda function that we're trying to execute the step function. The generic lambda function is looking for 2 values: clusterId and policyJsonName.

We're able to fetch the clusterId from an earlier state machine but now we would like to hard code policyJsonName within the state machine. So we have tried using Input and Parameter option of step function but that doesn't work and gives us a validation error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html

```
{
    "Comment": "Job Orchestration EMR Step",
    "dataset1": {"policyJsonName": "lambdainput"},
    "StartAt": "EMRFetchClusterId",
    "States": {
      "EMRFetchClusterId": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXX-fetch-clusterId",
        "ResultPath": "$.clusterId",
        "Next": "EMRAutoScaling"
      },
      "EMRAutoScaling": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXX-add-auto-scaling",
      "Parameters": {
      "comment": "Provide input to autoscaling in lambda function",
      "InputPath": "$.dataset1",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the link you mentioned, this portion:

```
{
  "comment": "Example for InputPath.",
  "dataset1": {
    "val1": 1,
    "val2": 2,
    "val3": 3
  },
  "dataset2": {
    "val1": "a",
    "val2": "b",
    "val3": "c"
  }
}
```

This is actually the **input to the state**, it's not a part of the state definition. You can confirm this because they say the following:

> For example, suppose the input to your state includes the following.

Instead, if you want to hardcode values, you have to pass it directly into a `Parameters` parameter, like this:

```
"Parameters": {
  "policyJsonName": "lambdainput"
}
```

Comment: I have tried the following and I get the syntax error:expected value of type: String, Null instead of Object.

      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXX-add-auto-scaling",
      "Parameters": {
      "comment": "Provide input to autoscaling in lambda function",
      "InputPath": {"policyJsonName": "lambdainput"}

Comment: Hmm I tried it through console and it worked with an object, but if you can only send a string then send a stringified json instead

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of a stringified json?

Comment: I edited my answer, I looked into it a bit more and what you want to use is the `Parameters` option without the `InputPath`. I changed the example to include what that will look like

Comment: Very strange..I have tried 

"Parameters": {
  "policyJsonName": "lambdainput"
}

Doesn't throw an error message but when the state machine runs doesn't pass the value under parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you want something like this,

```json
{
    "Comment": "Job Orchestration EMR Step",
    
    "StartAt": "EMRFetchClusterId",
    "States": {
      "EMRFetchClusterId": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXX-fetch-clusterId",
        "Next": "EMRAutoScaling"
      },
      "EMRAutoScaling": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXX-add-auto-scaling",
      "Parameters": {
        "comment": "Provide input to autoscaling in lambda function",
        "clusterId.$": "$.clusterId",
        "policyJsonName": "lambdainput"
      }
}
```

The `"clusterId.$": "$.clusterId"` special `.$` suffix syntax will a json path lookup of `$.clusterId` in the payload coming into `EMRAutoScaling` , as per the documentation [here](https://states-language.net/spec.html#payload-template)

> If any field within the Payload Template (however deeply nested) has a name ending with the characters ".$", its value is transformed according to rules below and the field is renamed to strip the ".$" suffix.

And `"lambdainput"` is just hard-coded as you specified.

**One note**
I removed `"dataset1": {"policyJsonName": "lambdainput"},` because the only top level fields allowed are  `"Comment", "StartAt", "States", "Version", "TimeoutSeconds"` according to [Top level fields](https://states-language.net/spec.html#toplevelfields) .